# Bounds.size.width is not the real width

Tags: ios, swift

I initialized two `button` in `StoreTabView.swift`:

`@IBDesignable class StoreTabView: UIView`

```
store_button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, height: self.bounds.size.height))

user_button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, height: self.bounds.size.height))
```

And in my storyboard I set the `view`'s class to `StoreTabView`, and set the `constrains`:

And I find the `self.bounds.size.width` is not the real width of it, in my `simulator-5s`, the logical resolution should be `320` rather than `375`, but In `Debug View Hierarchy`, I found it is `375`.

> [image]

And in the console I print two `button` to show detail:

```
<UIButton: 0x7fd79be63620; frame = (187.5 0; 187.5 45); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000023a9e0>>
Printing description of $7:
<UIButton: 0x7fd79be63360; frame = (0 0; 187.5 45); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000023a8e0>>
```

We can see the `width` is `187.5`, equals `375/2`, so,  `self.bounds.size.width` why is not `320` ? how to make the it to be `320` width? because the `button`'s width should be `160` rather than `187.5`.

Comment: Where are you checking self.bounds.size.width? If you're checking in your view controller class, it should be self.view.bounds.size.width

Comment: @Bhavuk Jain , I have edited my question, make the issue detail, please check.

Comment: just so you can see yourself, print, bounds/frame both together so you see their difference...

Comment: @Honey right , is `160`, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your basics -

The bounds of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to its own coordinate system (0,0).

The frame of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to the superview it is contained within.

Thank me later :)

Comment: As you can  see in my question, the running simulator is `5c`, and I have set the `contraints` to the `StoreTabView `.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use auto layout? In such matter it's easier to control and create views. If you are creating buttons from code I guess you're not using storyboard. Then constraint you are looking for looks like so.

```
buttonsSuperview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: buttonsSuperview, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 1.0))
```

Of course you're gonna need more than this constraint (for height and position also).

If you are using storyboard it's really easy. You drag connection from button to it's superview, set equal widths and then just modify constraint's multiplier.